# Creating a dynamic form with Meteor Spacebars

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I want to create a form that shows different sections depending on which template it belongs to. I want the data that the user enters to be reactive: if the user changes from one template to another, her previous entries should still be visible. I plan to create a "form" template, so that I can have a single `Template.form.events` function that will set the appropriate Session variables as the form is filled in.

My question is about how to populate the form dynamically. Here's how I've attempted to go about this, but all the fields appear all the time.

```
<body>
  {{> form1}}
  {{> form2}}
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  {{> form name=1 password=1}}
</body>

<template name="form1">
  {{#form name=1 species=1}}
    <h1>Form 1</h1>
  {{/form}}
</template>

<template name="form2">
  <h1>Form 2</h1>
  {{>form name=1 planet=1 asMenu=1}}
</template>

<template name="form">
  {{#if name=1}}
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="">
  {{/if}}
  {{#if species=1}}
    <input type="text" name="species" placeholder="Species" value="">
  {{/if}}
  {{#if planet=1}}
    {{#if asMenu=1}}
      <select name="">
        <option value="Erth">Erth</option> 
        <option value="Othr">Othr</option>
      </select>
    {{else}}
      <input type="text" name="planet" placeholder="Planet" value="">
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if password=1}}
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  {{/if}}
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</template>
```

Can you help me to understand how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly spacebars doesn't support comparisons so `{{#if var=1}}` is invalid syntax. However 1 is *true* so I'm going to take advantage of that to replace `{{#if name=1}}` with `{{#if name}}`:

```
<body>
  {{> form1}}
  {{> form2}}
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  {{> form name=1 password=1}}
</body>

<template name="form1">
  <h1>Form 1</h1>
  {{>form name=1 species=1}}
</template>

<template name="form2">
  <h1>Form 2</h1>
  {{>form name=1 planet=1 asMenu=1}}
</template>

<template name="form">
  {{#if name}}
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="">
  {{/if}}
  {{#if species}}
    <input type="text" name="species" placeholder="Species" value="">
  {{/if}}
  {{#if planet}}
    {{#if asMenu}}
      <select name="">
        <option value="Erth">Erth</option> 
        <option value="Othr">Othr</option>
      </select>
    {{else}}
      <input type="text" name="planet" placeholder="Planet" value="">
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if password}}
    <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  {{/if}}
  <br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</template>
```

Comment: `While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
reuse.html:11: Unexpected closing template tag
...rm 1</h1>   {{/form}}`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove your closing `{{/form}}` tag which shouldn't have there anyway.